# How to find folders that containt a certain string using CMD?

Tags: file, cmd, directory, findstr

I need to find the path of every folder that contains the words "test" or "Test" or "TEST" in a specific location. The file tree is huge.

This is to remove every folder that contains "test". I've tried using 
the findstr function.

```
findstr /i "test"
```

I expect to get every folder path that contains "test"

Comment: well, you told `findstr`, what to search *for*, but not, what to search *in*. Try `dir /s /b c:\* | findstr /i "test"`

Comment: Using `dir /s /b /a:d "*test*"` will find the directories. But, you still need something to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

The list of directories can be generated and iterated over using a `FOR` loop. When you are satisfied that the correct directories will be deleted, remove the `echo` from the line containing `rmdir`.

```
@echo off
pushd \
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:d "*test*"') do (
    echo if exist "%%~a" (rmdir /s /q "%%~a")
)
popd
```

If you wanted to push ahead into Powershell, which Microsoft says is the future, something like this might work. When you are satisfied that the correct directories will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

=== Remove-TestDirectories.ps1

```
$previousdir = ":" # set to impossible filesystem name

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path "C:\" -Filter "*test*" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Sort-Object -Property FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        #"{0} and {1} and {2}" -f @($previousdir, $_.FullName, $_.FullName.StartsWith($previousdir))
        if (-not $_.FullName.StartsWith($previousdir)) {
            $previousdir = $_.FullName
            if (Test-Path -Path $_.FullName) { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -WhatIf}
        }
    }
```

This can be run from a cmd.exe shell.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File Remove-TestDirectories.ps1
```